# How can I edit the number on a property data block?

Tags: python, drivers, properties, data-blocks

I have a property to hide a pair of glasses and hair on a character so it is easier to animate, but I want to change the number that turns the glasses off. When the property is 0 the hair disappears but the glasses are on, how can I change the glasses to disappear when the property is set to 0 instead of 1?

Here is a link of the glasses turned on and off- https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgxeg.jpg

Comment: This may help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31962/switching-visible-objects-via-driver/31967#31967

Comment: So Python has the keyword [not] and operator [ ! ].  1 - x  == 1 when x  is zero.  Next.  1 - x ==  zero when when x is 1.  This is called invert or inversion.  Python can convert 1 and zero .. to True and False respectively.   So these little facts can be used in a Python Driver.  Driver can be copied and pasted and modified.

Comment: Can you state your level of Python familiarity?  Beginner, Intermediate, Experienced, Very Experienced might be some choices.  I understand about 50% of what you wrote.  Perhaps 50% is adequate for a comment.  I suggest a screen capture of your Blender UI, to make your statement a bit clearer.  Lastly many readers, perhaps including you, can create an example like the one listed above and propose an answer. I hope that will happen and you can vote for someone who needs points.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I have zero experience with python. I'm just an animator/modeler lol

Comment: The first example I provided may be enough ... basically you are asking the question .. in Python .. is the value zero or one. If x ==0 or ... if x == 1.  I do not see a screen capture, so some will interpret your question as a little vague.  I hope you will consider an answer from someone with less than 3000 points.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger My bad here is the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/ups6JZ0

Comment: The goal is for you to provide the screen shot in your original question so that many readers will see it.  Many readers who need points can answer your question with the comments already provided.  Please place the image in your original question.   I am commenting and trying to accelerate an answer from others.  I am not trying to place an answer in this question.  Many others can do that.  Lastly the system will suggest we limit comments.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi Elven, although i am sure you don't wanna read it, but if you want to use not just very basic drivers you should learn at least some basic python. Of course we could now present a perfect answer for you by describing every little detail how to do that. But you wouldn't understand why it is working. So that's just my opinion, but that's a bit "waste of time" in my eyes. And if you are willing to learn a bit python you would be able to do some great things with it and it will open new horizons for you. That's a bit like carrying a baby from one place to another instead of teaching him to run.

Comment: @Chris I would be willing to learn some python if it will help me create a better animation workflow for myself. Where would I go to learn some basic python for blender?

Comment: @Elven_Randomness: That's depends strong on your likings. If you like learning by videos, e.g. here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw